# Populate 'files' property of Grunt task configuration via function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

EDITED:

Is there a way to dynamically populate the <s>`src`</s> `files` property of a task configuration in Grunt via function?

Example

```
concat: {
    angularSourceJs: {
        src: function() { 
            return angularSort(grunt.file.expand('src/**/*.js')); 
        },
        dest: 'dist/site.js'
    }
}
```

```
karma: {
    unit: {
        files: function() { 
            return angularSort(grunt.file.expand('src/**/*.js')); 
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

This would be very helpful in situations <s>like this, where the order of the files matters but defining that order is far more complex than simply changing the order in an array.</s> utilizing grunt-contrib-watch where it is not desired to reload Grunt.

Comment: Another point to consider is that the files enumerated by grunt.file.expand() may not include files that have yet to be generated (i.e. grunt-html2js) given that initConfig() runs prior to any tasks being run.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
concat: {
    angularSourceJs: {
        src: angularSort(grunt.file.expand('src/**/*.js')),
        dest: 'dist/site.js'
    }
}
```

Above assumes, that `angularSort` function returns array of sorted file paths.

Comment: What about in combination with grunt-contrib-watch? Would this value be recomputed if a file was altered or introduced?

Comment: No, you would need to restart a task if you add new file or change name of the file.

Comment: angularSort() is responsible for returning an array of sorted file paths. BTW, thanks for helping me see the obvious about my grunt-contrib-concat example.